# How to add a marker to OpenStreetMap with Gmap.NET?

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

I'm working on my first test project using GMap.NET and OpenStreenMap provider. I found some examples of how to add marker for Google Map provider, but struggling to do the same for OSM provider. The follwing code

```
GMapOverlay markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");
markersOverlay.Markers.Add(new GMapMarker(new PointLatLng(44.05946, -79.459518)));
```

gives me the following error:

*Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'GMapMarker'*

In the example for Google Map provider, GMarkerGoogle is being used, like so:

```
GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(-25.966688, 32.580528),
  new Bitmap("c:\images\mymarker.png");
```

but I cannot find any info on how to add marker for OpenStreetMaps.

Comment: to @AlexvanOostenrijk: thanks! It's nice to see some updated tutorials for the next time I need to work on that project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the provider:

```
yourMap.MapProvider = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap;
```

then if I remember correctly, something along the lines...

```
GMap.NET.PointLatLng point = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(1231231, 123123);
var marker = new GMapMarker(point);
```

or something like that...good luck :)

UPDATE:
Try GMarkerCross. here's the source code:https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/Markers/GMarkerCross.cs

Comment: This is one of the ways I already tried. This "new GMapMarker(point)" part is exactly the problem as GMapMarker is abstract class that you cannot create an instance of and cannot use it as a method either.

Comment: if thats the case, I suggest, get the latest source code https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest and find out if there is any class similar to GMarkerGoogle for openstreetmaps

Comment: I feel very stupid now, but GMarkerGoogle didn't work for me because I didn't add it to overlay, not because it wasn't good for OSM maps. There are two types of markers in GMap.NET - cross and google marker (which has many nice "types") and both work with any provider. Thank you for nudging me into the right direction.

Comment: Try GMarkerCross. here's the source code:https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/Markers/GMarkerCross.cs

Comment: Got it working with both Google marker and Cross marker! Thank you for your help!